# Update FileField: what is the name of the old file

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

When FileUpdate is called, I substitute the old file with a new one. 
I'd like to handle the old file. Namely move it to some other directory.

Could you have a look at the picture below. New file is called "C book 1.pdf". Existing file is called "4_Oracle_Database_11g_PLSQL_Fundamentals_PLSQL.pdf".

But at the breakpoint (see comment in form_valid), old_file_name = C book 1.pdf.

But I can't catch why. I call super(FileUpdate, self).form_valid(form) in a couple of lines. And only there self.object = form.save().

At the breakpoint I expect self.object to be the unchanged object. Existing one.

**Could you help me understand how to catch the file name of the old file.**

```
class UserFile(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, default=uuid.uuid4,
                            editable=False)
    user_file = models.FileField(verbose_name=_("file"),
                                 max_length=255,
                                 upload_to=get_file_path)

class FileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = UserFile
    form_class = FileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Delete old file.
        """
        parent_directory = get_parent_directory_of_file(self.object)
        old_file_name = self.object.user_file.name # Breakpoint
        self.object.user_file.delete()
        return super(FileUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is the form:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: To catch the file name, you might want to get it from the file's data before `is_valid()` is called - i.e. get it from the object instance before the model transaction takes place.

---

Regarding the deletion of your old file..

I believe calling `.delete()` doesn't actually delete the file - see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage).

An extract from the page:

> FileField instances are created in your database as varchar columns with a default max length of 100 characters.

This means that what's stored in the database is actually just the pathname/url to the file - not the actual file itself. So when you call `delete()`, you're essentially **only deleting the pathname**.

To delete a file you will have to use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) standard library:

You can do something like this:

```
import os

# change to the directory where the file exists relative to this current file
# in this case, it moves up 3 levels from the current file

cdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# join the previous path with the path to the file to be deleted
# this assumes files are uploaded to `media/user_uploads` - change as you deem fit

filepath = 'media/user_uploads/' + self.object.user_file.name
file_to_delete = os.path.join(cdir, filepath)

# delete the file
os.remove(file_to_delete)
```

More on `os.remove()` in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove). I haven't tested this but I guess you could give this a shot.